# How can I get all the parent nodes present in my firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a activity where the students can check their attendance of the particular month. On selecting the month, they will be directed to that month's dates on which they were present. The problem is that I'm able to get the data of dates on which they were present on listview but when I tried to access the 'month' node, the app stopped working.

```
Attendance Record
{
   AUGUST :
   {
      2019-08-31 : PRESENT
   }
   SEPTEMBER :
   {
      2019-09-02 : PRESENT
      2019-09-03 : PRESENT
   }
```

In short, I want to access the child of node 'Attendance Record'.

This is the code I used to insert the child nodes of 'Attendance Record' i.e 'AUGUST' & 'SEPTEMBER' in the listview:

```
databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Attendance Record");
databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                String data = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                arrayList.add(data);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

The stack trace :

```
2019-09-12 12:54:11.854 28475-28475/com.example.appattendance E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.appattendance, PID: 28475
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertString(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@18.0.1:408)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@18.0.1:199)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@18.0.1:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@18.0.1:212)
        at com.example.appattendance.Activity_Record$1.onChildAdded(Activity_Record.java:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ChildEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@18.0.1:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@18.0.1:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@18.0.1:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: Posted the stack trace

Comment: You are receiving the data in hashmap.

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this and check the output.

```
databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            Monthlist = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String monthkey = dsp.getKey();
                Monthlist.add(monthkey); //add result into array list
            }
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```